# Multiple UiViewController with one Class?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiviewcontroller, uinavigationcontroller

I have an iPad application that is using Storyboard.

I have a UINavigationController, that has the first UIViewController set as it's root view controller.

That VC then segue's through to various other VC's some of the Segues are triggered from UiButtons, other are called in methods in the VC class(i assume this is the correct way to set this up, i'm usually an OSX developer).

Currently i only have one class (ViewController) for the VC's, so they are all instances of the same class. It's quite a simple app so i found it easier to keep all the methods e.t.c in the one class file.

However i am seeing some weird issues, like being unable to manually call Segues when the app resumes e.t.c

Could these be cause by have the VC's be of the same class? What's the usual form for this?

Quite a lot of the VC's just contain some text and a button to click to the next VC, so i wouldn't actuality need any custom classes for those anyway, so creating different classes for the VC's that need it is not the biggest job in the world. But it does seem a waste of time if not necessary.

Sanity check gratefully appreciated!

Thanks

Gareth

Answer (score 0):

You should not need to subclass your view controller further.

Just make sure you have some way to know where you are in the navigation hierarchy. For instance, if you are trying to trigger a segue that is not available at a certain navigation level, you are bound to get an error.

For example, your navigation controller has the `viewControllers` property. You might be able to count them in order to determine where you are.

Comment: Hi Mundi, thanks for your reply. The weird issue I am seeing is progmatic Segues not occurring at all, with no errors of any kind. I have also tried just manually pushing the VC and that also seems to not work. It all seems to stem from a fast application switch to Safari that happens to do some OAuth. When the app loads back up, via a custom URL none of the coded segues of pushes work. However ones that are trigger from a UIbutton do. I have put some breakpoints in and it seems that the UInavigationController becomes nil?

Comment: Then maybe just reset the navigation controller with something like `popToRootViewController`.

Comment: I have tried - [self.navigationController popToRootViewControllerAnimated:NO]; but as self.navigationcontroller seems to be nil, nothing happens, and no error as I'm sending to nil. I guess I need to somehow stop the navigationcontroller from being released but I'm not sure how or where as I am not manually instantiating it anywhere, it just exists in the Storyboard.